# ffmpeg 4.2.3 bug. Pressing "y" do not overwrite the file

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg 4.2.3 bug: Do not overwrite the file even "y" is pressed

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i VIDEOFILES_short.txt -filter_complex  \
>  "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];  \
>   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];  \
>   [v1][v2]concat[v12];            \
>   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];  \
>   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];  \
>   [v3][v4]concat[v34];            \
>   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5];  \
>   [v5]vflip, hflip[v5flip];       \
>   [v12][v34][v5flip]concat=n=3:v=1, scale=1920:1080[out]" -map "[out]" -r 32 -crf 14  -vcodec libx264  -vb 20M   video_out_FF.avi
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55f126a78400] Invalid mdhd time scale 0, defaulting to 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55f126a78400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[concat @ 0x55f126a6dbc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[concat @ 0x55f126a6dbc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, concat, from 'VIDEOFILES_short.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60138 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 60010 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T17:51:41.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 17:51:42:25
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T17:51:41.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 17:51:42:25
    Stream #0:2: Unknown: none
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T17:51:41.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro MET
    Stream #0:4: Unknown: none
File 'video_out_FF.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Not overwriting - exiting
```

Comment: This is a question and answer website.  Did you have a question?  To report FFMPEG bugs, go here https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: I agree with you :)

Comment: Was this a bug? What were the permissions of the output file, current directory, and what was the content of the text file you have given to ffmpeg as input?